# Why is my django template context processor not getting called

Tags: django, django-templates

I must have missed something in setting up a custom template context as it's never getting called.

In settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django_authopenid.context_processors.authopenid",
    "web.context_processors.my_hat",
)
```

in web/context_processors.py

```
from libs.utils import get_hat, get_project, my_hats

print 'heloooo'

def my_hat(request):
    """Insert some additional information into the template context
    """
     
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()

    print 'hiiiiiiii'

    return {'hat': get_hat(request),
        'project': get_project(request),
        }
```

nothing is output and django processes view and displays template without ever hitting this.  What have I missed!?

**Thanks Insin, the bits I had missed:**

In the view.py

```
return render_to_response(template, {
        'tasks': tasks,
    },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In the template:

```
  My current hat is {{hat}}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you remember to use [RequestContext](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1) when rendering the template?

As of Django 1.3, there is a new shortcut function, [`render`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), which uses `RequestContext` by default: :

```
return render(request, template, {
    'tasks': tasks,
})
```

Comment: No as from my extensive googling the examples don't show it!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557460/django-having-middleware-communicate-with-views-templates
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025025/django-context-processor-trouble
http://lethain.com/entry/2007/jun/14/a-django-middleware-for-google-analytics-repost/
...

Comment: Using `render` rather than `render_to_response` seemed to be the easiest solution for me.